# Laravel-mix acusa erro na sintaxe quando não há nenhum

Tags: npm, webpack, yarn, laravel

Boa noite galera, estou tentando rodar NPM RUN DEV e quando o faço ele acusa um erro que não faz sentido pra mim (apesar de ser um iniciante total em laravel).

```
[webpack-cli] /var/www/html/guild-cd17/webpack.mix.js:26
"scripts": {
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
at new Script (vm.js:101:7)
at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (/var/www/html/guild-cd17/node_modules/v8-compile- 
cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
at Module._compile (/var/www/html/guild-cd17/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile- 
cache.js:184:36)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (/var/www/html/guild-cd17/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile- 
cache.js:159:20)
at module.exports (/var/www/html/guild-cd17/node_modules/laravel- 
mix/setup/webpack.config.js:8:5)
at /var/www/html/guild-cd17/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:908:43
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! guild-cd17@1.0.0 development: `mix`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the guild-cd17@1.0.0 development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output 
above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rafael/.npm/_logs/2021-01-30T22_30_18_667Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! guild-cd17@1.0.0 dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the guild-cd17@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output 
above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rafael/.npm/_logs/2021-01-30T22_30_18_732Z-debug.log
```

Segue abaixo o meu arquivo **webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
```

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mix Asset Management
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
| for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
| file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
|
*/

```
mix.js('resources/js/scripts.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/styles.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer')
.setPublicPath('public')
]);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
mix.version();
};

"scripts": {
"dev": "npm run development",
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -- 
progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev- 
server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"prod": "npm run production",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no- 
progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
}
```

Estou desde as 13:00 tentando resolver pesquisando e me virando mas até agora nada. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive um problema parecido (o erro de sintaxe era outro mas também parecia um erro inválido).

A solução para mim foi atualizar o Node e o npm.

Para verificar a versão do Node: `node -v`

Para verificar a versão do npm: `npm -v`

Você não mencionou qual sistema operacional usa. Vou passar as instruções para o Ubuntu/Linux.

Para atualizar o Node (instruções retiradas de https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version e de https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall libssl-dev
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.2/install.sh | bash
nvm install node
```

Para atualizar o npm:

```
npm update -g
```

No meu caso era o Node que estava desatualizado.